# Eclipse Project Explorer Highlighting

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windows-7-x64

I installed the [Eclipse Moonrise UI](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme#.U9KEY_ldV8E) and the results are great, except a couple things become unreadable for me. [Here is an image](http://postimg.org/image/kuwo59kxn/) of what my project explorer window looks like. I have 2 git repositories which have black text, making it very difficult to read on the dark background. The normal files and folders have light text, but when selected, it becomes completely unreadable because the selected item's background is very light. Also my scroll bars are light (unlike what is seen on the front page of the above link).
I am unable to locate where I can adjust these settings.

On the other hand, the Outliner window has light text on the dark background and when selected becomes dark text on a light background. Not the way it is supposed to look with this plugin, but it's fine, I can read it.

I am running  Kepler Service Release 2 on windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Except for scrollbars that are forced by OS theme, try to import the epf file as suggested on project page. The settings contained in that epf will influence the syntax highlighting (foreground/background colors) for code editors but also custom colors for other views (eg. console, git filenames, etc.).

If instead you're using CDT, unfortunately the issues with package explorer and outline file names cannot be solved now, because those colors are hard-coded in that package and requires a fix in CDT bundle for them before.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but after importing the RainbowDrops.epf file, the colors in the package explorer are mostly the same. The only change there was to the non-selected git repositories. The color of those did improve, but selected items are still white on white.